What gadgets are needed to bypass the Advanced Thunder Barriers?
Apparently all Advanced Thunder Barriers have a bypass method. I have the Thunderbird Feather / Plume and the Memento Lens, and am only a few levels to getting my Electrograna strong enough to pass Advanced Barriers.
Is there anything that ability would let me do that I can't do yet? Other than "pass through barriers mid-combat"?

if you look  around the web, players don't even agree on advanced barriers actually existing in the fist place

@SPArcheon-onstrike - Oh I know they exist. The beach barrier with a Seelie inside couldn't be accessed with Intermediate, I bypassed it with the Lens, and the Wiki has three different symbols for each type.

that is part of the issue. I never bothered myself to check, but some claim that the "advanced" barriers are a scrap mechanic and every "advanced" barrier is either a plot barrier (see the one on Ei archon quest story boss) or part of a puzzle and can be disabled. Basically the point is that many think that by the time you get the ability you will have completed all the puzzle that you could skip with the ability.

@SPArcheon-onstrike - Well, I haven't beaten the Delusion Factory so that story boss barrier might still be a use for the Advanced Unlock, maybe.

If my memory serves that barrier can't be crossed even with the "advanced" upgrade, and the game even has a special message for it if you try.

@SPArcheon-onstrike - Where's that barrier so I can test it?

If you follow the stairs going down from Nakurami Shrine, soon or later you should pass by a barrier to a small cave. As now, I can only provide you a picture found on the web

@SPArcheon-onstrike - That's an Elementary (LV 1) Barrier? https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Thunder_Barrier#Barrier_Levels - I already went in there, and I think it fell permanently for me after Cleansing the Sakura or something. It's not there anymore for me. It also doesn't seem a plot relevant location?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
